# Boolean union not working properly

Tags: modifiers, artifacts

Whenever I try to use a boolean operation to union two objects together strange patterns appear on on the object selected in the boolean modifier, it also affects any material I try to hide it with and makes it unuseable.

As I rotate the camera the weird pattern moves and transforms

[image: boolean issue1]

[image: boolean issue 2]

Comment: Booleans don't work well with large open surfaces (such as a flat planes) - blender often must choose places to place an edge through an existing face in order to accommodate the boolean operation. Thus, ugly topology that does not shade well is often created. One way to mitigate this is to make sure that the target object is sufficiently subdivided, so the new vertices added by the boolean operation have a place to connect "relatively cleanly" to. You may still have to manually re-topologize afterwards, though not as much as if you perform the operation on an un-subdivided object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very new to booleans and did not understand how they worked, I added in a load of loop cuts and it sorted it out