# Boolean Union Modifier not working

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

I am currently creating a character for 3d printing, but when I try to join to intersecting parts with boolean modifier, **strange patterns appear over the targeted mesh.** The patterns shift around and glitch when navigating the viewport, and **nothing changes when the modifier is applied** **(it doesn't seem to actually unify the mesh either)**

(Modifier on cloak, targeting body)

[image]

(Modifier on body, targeting cloak)

[image]

It is not just these two meshes, it happens with **any two intersecting meshes** on this model.

**Note that all of the meshes are manifold and have similar mesh resolution.**

The only other post on this issue I found was a similar unanswered question from 8 months ago on here - [Boolean union not working properly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264260/boolean-union-not-working-properly)

This is my first time creating a character for this purpose, so any help with how to fix this or alternatives would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It's possible you might be experiencing Z-Fighting with your mesh. From your description and images it looks like that could be your problem. (Rough information on what Z-Fighting is and why it occurs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)

Comment: @Zack Thank you so much, It turns it was z-fighting, but after trying to fix it, I realised I had made a really simple mistake, and the reason the z-fighting happened was because I hadn't hid the target mesh. I thought that the modifier acted more like the join command than the other boolean operations so I was rendering two copies on top of each other. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is just to hide the original instance of the target mesh on the modifier :) The boolean modifier doesn't join the two meshes, so one object is rendered twice and causes Z-fighting.